# I want to repeat an input question but I don't want to get its output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to do confirmation question from a selection question
e.g

```
x_selection = 0 
x_confirmation = 0
while x_selection = 0:
    x = input("are you hungry").lower
    if x == "yes"
        print("Well heres some food")
        x_selection = 1
    elif x == "no"
        print("Alright then")
```

then I want to make a confirmation question using x (our input question) but I don't the output of x but x's original question.
I attempted this

```
while x_confirmation == 0:
    x_confirm = input("Are you sure this is right?").lower
    if x_confirm == "yes":
        print("yay")
        x_confirmation = 1
    elif x_confirm == "no":
        print("nay")
        x_selection = 0
        print(x)
```

I want x as the question not as the answer and repeat the sequence of while confirmation x_selection == 0. Any Tips will help me. (my problem is that i want x as the question not x as the output). Expected Output: "Are you hungry" (and I can say again if I'm hungry or not if I said no the x_confirm question) But my Acutal Output was either Yes or No, the answer from first and only time i had run the code (sorry if i'm horribly explaining this, i'm new-ish to coding and I don't know what to write and not write)

Comment: So don't reassign `input` to `x`? Also, you meant `lower()`, not `lower`

Comment: hi, can you state what the actual problem is? At the moment we just have some code you have tried but you didn't say specifically what it's doing wrong.

Comment: I'm saying that my problem is that x will not give me the question it will only give the output of that question when i ran it beforehand so when i run it again it will give me either Hi or goodbye as my answer

Comment: It would be easier for folks to help if you show that in the question (example of expected output, and example of actual output)

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the first loop, you have this loop condition:

```
while x_selection = 0:
```

I think you mean to use the equality comparison operator `==` here, rather than the assignment operator `=`.

Because of this typo, Python makes the assignment by setting x_selection to 0, instead of using it as a loop control variable as you intended.

So fixing the operator to `==` should solve that.

Comment: Okay yes I'm explaining this very bad, i keep doing typos and I'm basically wasting your time, so I'm sorry, I have put == in that line of code in my case but since I'm a moron, I forgot to add it in here so just leave it, i figure out someway later on, thank you for putting up with my ignorance and I also tried to using a sample code and not the actual thing as you can tell so I have helped literally no-one with this.

Comment: @justbeingnev you are welcome. Please have a look at this link, which has helpful tips about that, as it's all too easy for anyone to make mistakes when posting code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example